# Parsing a Connection String

Tags: c#, connection-string, string-parsing

Is there a standard library or code snippet to get a value with a connection string like this?

```
string connstr = "DataServiceUrl=http://localhost/foo;" + 
        "RemoteServerConnection={server=http://localhost/foo2;interface=0.0.0.0;};" + 
        "publisherport=1234;StatisticsURL=http://localhost/foo3";
```

The whole inner connection property is kind of throwing this in a loop.  I'd like to get specific values based on a key.

Here was the answer posted by John I used:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionStringBuilder(); 
builder.ConnectionString = this.ConnectionString;
MessageBox.Show(builder["RemoteServerConnection"]);
```

Comment: See [Connection String Builders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947.aspx)

Comment: @JohnSaunders you really should just post that as a answer.

Comment: An answer that short would bring downvotes. I don't have time for a longer answer.

Comment: Here's the code to post and I'll give you credit for the answer              System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.ConnectionString = this.ConnectionString;
            MessageBox.Show(builder["RemoteServerConnection"]);

Comment: @dave2118 you can post that that as an answer ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacing "`{`" and "`}`" by (`"`) does the trick:

```
string conn = "DataServiceUrl=http://localhost/foo;" +
    "RemoteServerConnection={server=http://localhost/foo2;interface=0.0.0.0;};" +
    "publisherport=1234;StatisticsURL=http://localhost/foo3";

var builder = new System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.ConnectionString = conn.Replace("{", "\"").Replace("}", "\"");
var keys = builder.Keys;
var values = builder.Values;
string remoteServerConnection = (string)builder["RemoteServerConnection"];
```