# Regular expression for tokenizing connection string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have 2 different types of connection strings (because of legacy reasons that I can't fix everywhere for various reasons which are irrelevant here). I need to break them up into key/value pairs. Here are the sample connection strings:

```
1. Server=SomeServer;Database=SomeDatabase;Something=Hello
2. Server=SomeServer,Database=SomeDatabase;Something=Hello
3. Server=SomeServer,1111;Database=SomeDatabase;Something=Hello
```

For the first 2 cases, I can use the regex:

```
(?<Key>[0-9A-z\s]+)=(?<Val>[0-9A-z\s,]+?[0-9A-z\s]+)
```

For the third one, I can use the regex:

```
(?<Key>[0-9A-z\s]+)=(?<Val>[0-9A-z\s]+?[0-9A-z\s,]+)
```

How do I turn this into one regex that would work for all cases?

Comment: What's the purpose of `[0-9A-z\s,]+?[0-9A-z\s]+`? It's [dangerous](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: Maybe [use DbConnectionStringBuilder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524611/parsing-a-connection-string) would work?

Comment: @Rawing: The first part did a lazy match which caught the first letter after the "=" - then I tried to capture the rest with a greedy match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion.

```
(?<key>[^=;,]+)=(?<val>[^;,]+(,\d+)?)
```

The semicolon is a delimiter as is the comma if it is not immediately followed by numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the below regex

```
(?<Key>[^=;]+)=(?<Val>[^;]+)
```

What the above uses is negated character class. `[^;]+` will select everything till the first `;` it encounters.

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/yD1yX7/2) (I've removed the named groups for testing. It would work well in C#, however)

Comment: @Denis why do you want to use it like that? I mean there is no uniformity.

Comment: It's something that was inherited. You're right it sux, just don't have any control over it...

Comment: How would you use this in c# to loop over the matches?